# AutoSize в dataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

как один столбец датагрид растянуть по его ширине, а остальные заполнением? Если делаю все филл, содержимое одного из столбцов не помещается, а если автосайз - половина грида пустая - не красиво(

Answer (score 0):

У `DataGridView` есть настройка `AutoSizeColumnsMode`

```
DataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells
```

Вот подробная ссылка на [DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewautosizecolumnsmode(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: я их уже все попробовал. Этот точно так-же половину грида пустым оставляет.

Comment: добавьте ваш код к вопросу так будет проще найти проблему

Answer (score 0):

А откуда данные попадают? Количество столбцов известно?
В любом случае, надо будет каждый столбец отдельно задавать:

```
col1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
col2.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

И каждый столбец должен быть объявлен, чтобы его можно было менять.

```
DGV1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {col1,col2});
```

Попробуй так.